# Find percentile of Discrete Probability Distribution

Tags: percentile

This is just a hypothetical question that I had (I made this question myself, just am curious about something). What if we were trying to find the $20\text{th}$ percentile in a discrete probability distribution from $0 \leq x \leq 5$, where

$F(0) = 0.1$

$F(1) = 0.3$

$F(2) = 0.5$

$F(3) = 0.6$

$F(4) = 0.8$

$F(5) = 1$

$F(x)$ is the cdf of course.

Would the $20\text{th}$ percentile be $0$ or $1$ or something else entirely?

This is where the $20\text{th}$ percentile is the value above or equal to $20%$ of the data

Can anyone give me the algorithm to find percentile in a discrete probability distribution if there is one?

Thank you for any help/comments.

Comment: What is your definition of the $20$th percentile?

Comment: 20th percentile is to me, the value that is above or equal to 20% of the data

Comment: $10\%$ of the data is $0$ or less so $90\%$ is $1$ or more; $30\%$ of the data is $1$ or less so $70\%$ is $2$ or more, ...

Comment: so you're saying that it's okay to go over 20% percent of the data in this specific case, as long as we're not BELOW the percentile (20%). So the correct answer in this case would be 1, not 2, 3, 4, or 5, because 1 is the minimum value that exceeds the percentile set (20%) correct? If we use 0, we're below it so that's not right. So it's okay to go over in this case with picking the 20th percentile value to be 1 because there's no way to be above or equal to exactly 20% of the data right?

Comment: I think you are looking for the value $k$ where $P(X < k) \le 0.2 \le P(X \le k)$.  For $k=0$ you have $P(X < 0) =0$  and $P(X \le 0)=0.1$; for $k=1$ you have $P(X < 1) =0.1$  and $P(X \le 1)=0.3$;  for $k=2$ you have $P(X < 2) =0.3$  and $P(X \le 2)=0.5$; one of those works and the other two do not

Comment: Why doesn't $1$ work? shouldn't $0.1 \leq 0.2 \leq 0.3$ be correct? (I edited my comment from earlier to fix the mistake of using 2, I should have written 1 to be the 20th percentile value, sorry!)

Comment: $1$ does work, as you say

Comment: Ah perfect. Thanks a lot. But I have a question about using this algorithm to check my answer $P(X<k) \leq p \leq P(X \leq k) $. Does this algorithm always work? Also is my intuitive thinking of "since we can't be at exactly p, just go the next closest x value that has a F(x) above p" wrong? (Where p is the percentile)

Comment: It works in general though there may be more than one solution.  If in your example you looked for the median ($50\%$) then $k$ could be $2$ or $3$ or any number in between them such as $2.5$

Comment: If there's more then one solution. How would I know which number to pick then as my percentile? The smallest one?

Comment: All the solutions would then be correct, so it is an arbitrary choice - some people take the middle of the range of values, but that too is arbitrary

Comment: Got it, thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*From comments:* I think you are looking for the value $k$ where $P(X<k)≤0.2≤P(X≤k)$

- for $k=0$ you have $P(X<0)=0$ and $P(X≤0)=0.1$
- for $k=1$ you have $P(X<1)=0.1$ and $P(X≤1)=0.3$
- for $k=2$ you have $P(X<2)=0.3$ and $P(X≤2)=0.5$
- $\cdots$

so the $20\%$ percentile is at the value $1$ for this distribution.

This approach works in general, but though there may be more than one solution. If in your example you had been looking for the median $(50\%)$ then $k$ could be $2$ or $3$ or any number in between;  all these solutions would then be correct, so it is an arbitrary choice - some people conventionally take the middle of the range of correct values so here $2.5$ for the median, but that too is arbitrary.